# Jquery ajax with google app engine post method

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, google-app-engine

Just trying to learn using ajax with appengine,started with the post method,but it does not work.
This is my HTML Code for the page

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title> Hello </title>
<script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
var data={"name":"Hola"};
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#subbut').click(function(){
$.ajax({

 url: '/test',
 type: 'POST',
 data: data,
 success: function(data,status){

    alert("Data" + data +"status"+status);
  }
 });
 });
 });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form method="post" action="/test">
 <input type="submit" id="subbut">
 </form>
 <div id="success"> </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Here goes my python code to render the above html code , its handler is /test1

```
from main import *

class TestH1(Handler):
      def get(self):
              self.render('tester.html')
```

And this is the python script to which AJAX request must be sent to,handler is /test.

```
    from main import * 
    import json
    class TestH(Handler):
        def post(self):
             t=self.request.get('name')
             output={'name':t+" duck"}
             output=json.dumps(output)
             self.response.out.write(output)
```

Expected behavior is that when i click on submit button,i get an alert message saying "Hola duck" , get nothing instead.
Any help would be appreciated as i am just starting with AJAX and Jquery withGAE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, I suppose you should suppress default behavior of form submitting when you press submit button by adding "return false" to the .click function. But I suppose it would be better to use just

```
<input type="button" id="subbut">
```

instead (even without form).

Then you should add "dataType: 'json'" to your ajax call to tell jQuery what type of data  you expect from server. Doing this you will be able to get response data by property names like "data.name". So:

```
var data={"name":"Hola"};
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#subbut').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/test',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data,status){
                alert(data.name);
                alert("Data" + data +"status"+status);
            }
       });
       return false;
    });
});
```

and it would be better if you set appropriate content type header to your response:

```
response.headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
self.response.out.write(output)
```

Comment: I removed the <form method="post"> and it worked. Is it because ajax is already posting to server and i don't need another post?

Comment: Sure. AJAX and forms are two different ways of sending data to server. The difference is that form submitting always reloads the page and AJAX is making the request in the background. You just mixed them. You can make ajax calls not only by button click, but by any event available in the browser.